# Datatables no reconoce VueJs

Tags: datatables, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente componente creado, si ven, tengo dos console.log() dentro del método mounted, uno fuera de datatables y el otro dentro, y el que esta adentro de datatables me tira error que no reconoce.
"Cannot read property 'roundtwo' of undefined"

```
<template>

    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="dt_results">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Posición</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Jugador</th>                          
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="text-center">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
          return{
              roundtwo:false
          }   
        },
        mounted() {

            console.log(this.roundtwo);     

           $("#dt_results").DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                stateSave: true,
                responsive: true,
                language:{
                    "url": '/datatable_spanish.json'
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "method": "post",
                    "url": '/results/getResultsDraw',
                    "data": {id_draw:$("#draw").val()} 
                },
                "columns": [ 
                    {
                       "data": "position", name: 'results_draw.position', "mRender": function (data, type, row, gg) {      

                             console.log(this.roundtwo);

                            return  row.position;                                     
                        },
                    },
                    { 
                       "data": "last_name", name: 'users.last_name', "mRender": function (data, type, row, gg) {    
                            return row.nickname != null ? row.nickname + ' ' + row.last_name : row.first_name + ' ' + row.last_name;                                     
                        },
                    },      
                ]
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Y si dentro de datatables cuando creo una columna le paso un método, tampoco reconoce!

Comment: No te funciona básicamente porque estas fuera del scope, debes usar una arrow function en vez de usar function solo, quedando `"mRender": (data, type, row, gg) => {console.log(this.roundtwo); return row.position;}` o la otra forma seria creando una variable `x` que sea igual a `this` antes de la funcion y usar esa variable

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto @GermanAlzate, ahora te hago una pregunta, si yo a algún mRender le agrego un botón y le quiero pasar un v-on:click="method", no me lo toma, si inspecciono el elemento una vez cargada la página, no lo renderiza y me lo muestra como string al v-on.

Comment: tendría que ver como lo haces, si es necesario abre otra pregunta

Comment: Ahi levante otra pregunta. Gracias @GermanAlzate https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86701/problemas-con-directivas-de-vue-en-datatables